# Проблема с COMET (Long polling)

Tags: jquery, comet, ajax, php

На хостинге есть два файла ajax.php (все запросы) и comet.php (Long polling), примерный код таков:

**ajax.php**

```
$answer = array();
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'test':        
            $answer = array('msg'=>'answer ajax.php');
            break;
        //...
    }
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');    
echo json_encode($answer);
```

**comet.php**

```
set_time_limit(0);
$sec = 300;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $sec; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');    
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Прошло '.$sec.' секунд'));
```

Теперь проблема: делаю ajax запрос к comet.php, следом делаю запрос к ajax.php. ajax.php не обрабатывает запрос (да и сайт перезагрузить не могу), пока не "освободиться" comet.php. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечу сам, может, кто-нибудь столкнётся с подобной проблемой!

Проблема была из-за одновременного доступа к файлам сессии, в начале файла ajax.php и comet.php была строка:

```
require ('init.php'); // разные настройки, а также запуск сессии(session_start())
```

Решение - в файле comet.php дописать:

```
require ('init.php');
//данные сессии сохранить в переменной ... и закрыть сессию
session_write_close();
//после этого уже можно делать зацикливание для Long polling ...
```

**P.S.** В самом вопросе я не написал про `session_start()` - моё упущение, никак не мог подумать, что это может быть причиной...

Comment: @rooty ))) Пару дней назад, я уже давал [аналогичный ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/391420#391484). Пользуйтесь поиском.

**P.S.** И всё же, посмотрите в сторону websockets.

Comment: Да вот именно искал, плохо, наверное. )) websockets - это следующее, с чем буду разбираться...

Answer (score 2):

Не городите костылей с Comet. Существует валидный подход **websockets**. Проблема актуальна для [IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets), но можно воспользоваться fallback с [flash-ом](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js).

Для бекэнда существует демон [Ratchet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet), построенный поверх [ReactPHP](https://github.com/reactphp/react). Настраивается быстро - разобрался за вечер. Умеет работать с вышеприведённым fallback-ом.

Или можно поддержать нашу отечественную разработку [phpdaemon](https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon) за авторством [Василия Зорина](http://habrahabr.ru/users/TravisBickle/). В своё время настроил с трудом (неактуальная документация) + терялись в неизвестности некоторые запросы.

Если всё же хочется `long polling`, то посмотрите в сторону [dklab_realplexor](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/) за авторством [Дмитрия Котерова](http://habrahabr.ru/users/DmitryKoterov/), либо вот [ещё один инструмент](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/).

**Бонус  на посмеяться:** [Разработка RealTime веб приложений](http://vimeo.com/23575335)

Мой интерес к реалтайму начался именно с этого видео.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в неправильном выборе технологии и реализации. 
Для интерактивности нужно использовать [websockets](http://learn.javascript.ru/websockets).

Comment: Я знаю про WebSocket, но хотелось бы сначала(так как серверная часть у WebSocet сложнее) разобраться с этим(Long polling) так сказать для "повышения опыта"...

Comment: Мало толку будет от "опыта" работы с устаревшей технологией.. Вебсокет-сервер подымается на ноде.жс очень легко, и работать с ним на клиенте также несложно, масса примеров в сети.