# Описание протокола websockets на русском языке

Tags: websocket

Подскажите, не встречалось ли вам описание протокола websockets на русском языке? Мне требуется реализовать этот протокол с наименьшими затратами времени.

Есть ли тесты для проверки? К примеру html страница могла бы посылать разные запросы и требовать определенных ответов.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, переведенной на руской спеки или ее куска по вебсокетам не существует. Несколько тестовых клиентов гуглятся, какого-то признанного набора тестов мне не попадалось

Comment: "Websocket - один из видов comet" @MAXOPKA, вы сильно ошибаетесь. Comet - это костыль использующий различные хаки: polling (он же ajax обыкновенный), long polling (скрытый iframe) и др. Т.е. всё то, что использовалось до появления Websocket и используется в угоду совместимости с браузерами. [Почитайте wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Implementations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал.

Вспомогательные классы:

```
class VString{ public: unsigned char *data; unsigned int sz; }; // Используется как указатель на данные
class MString : public VString{ }; // Используется для выделения памяти
```

Функции кодирования / декодирования.

```
void DecodeData(VString read){
    // need more data
    if(read.sz <= 4)
        return ;

    int fin = *read.data, opcode = fin&15, lpos;
    uint64 len = *(read.data+1);
    unsigned int mask = len & 128;

    if(opcode == LWSOC_CLOSE){
        wel.closed();
        return ;
    }

    switch(len&127){
        case 126:
            len = *(unsigned short*)(read.data+2);
            lpos = 4;
        break;
        case 127:
            if(read.sz<10)
                return ;
            len = *(uint64*)(read.data+2);
            lpos = 10;
        break;
        default:
            lpos = 2;
            len &= 127;
        break;
    }

    // need more data
    if(read.sz < lpos || read.sz < lpos + len + (mask ? 4 : 0))
        return ;

    if(mask){
        mask = *(unsigned int*)(read.data+lpos);
        lpos += 4;
    }

    if(len > S1M){
        wel.closed();
        return ;
    }

    if(mask){
        unsigned char *l = read.data + lpos;
        unsigned char *t = read.data + lpos + len;
        unsigned char *ft = t - (lpos + len) % 4;
        unsigned char *m = (unsigned char*)&mask;

        for(l; l < ft; l += 4)
            *(unsigned int*)l ^= mask;

        for(l; l < t; l++)
            *l ^= *m++;
    }

    AnalysData(wel, opcode, read.str(lpos, len));
    return ;
}

EncodeData(int type, VString data, int fin = 1){
    unsigned char buf[10];
    int mask = rand(), lpos;

    if(!data)
        mask = 0;

    buf[0] = (fin << 7) + (type&15);

    if(data.sz <= 125){
        buf[1] = 128 + data.sz;
        lpos = 2;
    }else if(data.sz <= 65535){
        buf[1] = 128 + 126;
        *(unsigned short*)(buf + 2) = data.sz;
        lpos = 4;
    } else{
        buf[1] = 128 + 127;
        *(uint64*)(buf + 2) = data.sz;
        lpos = 10;
    }

    MString ret;
    ret.Reserv(lpos + (mask ? 4 : 0) + data.sz);
    if(!ret)
        return MString();

    unsigned char *l = ret.data + lpos + (mask ? 4 : 0);

    memcpy(ret.data, buf, lpos);
    memcpy(l, data, data);

    if(mask){
        unsigned char *t = l + data.sz;
        unsigned char *ft = t - (data.sz % 4);
        unsigned char *m = (unsigned char*)&mask;

        memcpy(ret.data + lpos, &mask, 4);

        for(l; l < ft; l += 4)
            *(unsigned int*)l ^= mask;

        for(l; l < t; l++)
            *l ^= *m++;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Протестировано на работе с клиентом посылающим строки. Не реализована поддержка фреймов.

PS. Подскажите, зачем нужна маска? Я так и не понял ее смысл. От чего конкретно она защищает?

Comment: Эта защита от cache poisoning, вот на большом so описано: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174184/what-is-the-mask-in-a-websocket-frame, вот на русском (внизу статьи): http://learn.javascript.ru/websockets