# Падает нативный код на c++ под андроид

Tags: c++, android, native

Написал библиотеку с нативными функциями под андроид. Собственно, вот эти функции: [Описание протокола websockets на русском языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422766). На компьютере эти функции работают отлично. Наконец дошли руки до запуска на андроиде и в `EncodeData()` программа вылетает с ошибкой.

Вылетает на этой строке, на первой итерации:

```
*(unsigned int*)l ^= mask;
```

Если убрать маску `(mask = 0)`, то функция работает без ошибок.

В чем проблема в этом коде? Чем заменить, чтобы работало?

Comment: Нужно больше кода. Что за "l", там может быть не выравненный на "4" адрес?

Comment: Похоже на то, что если маска статически равна нулю, то всю строчку выбрасывает оптимизатор как ненужную. А что у вас в переменной `l`?

Comment: Жуть какая-то. l - это, похоже указатель. Рискну предположить, что там доступ по невыровненному адресу. Накладывайте маску побайтово.

Comment: Действительно, была ошибка в невыровненном адресе. В чем разница с архитектурой x86?

Comment: Некоторые инструкции на некоторых архитектурах хотят работать с выровненными данными. x86 - не исключение.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, x86 не требует *aligned access* в подавляющем количестве случаев, встретить обратное довольно сложно.

Comment: Я говорил про некоторые. SSE тому пример.

Comment: Кстати, а с порядком байт у Вас все нормально? Не нужно длины и проч. int крутить в/из сетевого при обмене (все же Х86 и некорые ARM little-endian, а другие (и сама сеть) big-endian)

Answer (score 8):

Я посмотрел Ваш код по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422766/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-websockets-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Действительно, это проблема с выравниванием. Для некоторых архитектур (в частности ARM) необходимо, чтобы обращения к памяти имели *естественное выравнивание*, т.е. адрес памяти должен быть кратен размеру данных (2 для short, 4 для int, 8 для uint64_t и double).

У Вас это происходит из-за величины lpos (даже в предположении, что ret.data выровнена на границу слова (или двойного слова, как обычнно возвращает malloc())).

Похоже, что проще всего будет перед основным циклом

```
    for(l; l < ft; l += 4)
        *(unsigned int*)l ^= mask;
```

добавить несколько строчек

```
   for(; l < t && l & 0x3; l++) { // цикл выполнится 0, 1, 2 или 3 раза
      *l ^= *m;
      mask = (mask << 8) | ((mask >> 24) & 0xff); // циклический сдвиг влево на 1 байт
   }
```

которые (по идее, на компе не проверял) побайтово меняют данные, пока не достигнуто выравниваание подходящее для int и крутят маску так, чтобы в следующем цикле для int она осталась правильной.

Answer (score 4):

Это называется "неопределенное поведение", также известное как "UB".

Если `l` имеет тип `unsigned char*`, то каст `(unsigned int*) l` работает как `reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(l)`.

В требованиях к `reinterpret_cast` написано что для каста `T1*` в `T2*` выравнивание `T1` должно быть не меньше выравнивания `T2`, иначе значение результата каста не определено.

Сам по себе каст безобиден, но вот разыменование указателя имеющего такое неопределенное значение приводит к UB.